# How to save multiple datasets into one file?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have 2 strongly typed datasets. I need to save the containing data into single file (And of course be able to read and load them back into datasets later.). Usually I use `DataSet.WriteXml()` method to save the data as text and `DataSet.ReadXml()` to read it when I have single dataset.

The first idea that is coming to mind is to save each dataset into Memory Stream, then convert the streams to byte arrays, and then write the bytes into the file.

But this idea looks to me not very elegant or best so I was wondering if there is better way of doing it.

**Any ideas?** (*Coded answers would be more helpful*)

Comment: There are a variety of file-based database engines.  Why not use one of those to store relational data in a file?

Comment: I have WinForms application. My datasets represent file. Let's say this is requirement.

Comment: Are these two datasets related to each other?  Related as in, they both have a key that can be related to each other, a primary key and foreign key?

Comment: If you have access to MS Excel, you could export the DataSets to the Excel file and each DataTable within the Set will have its own Worksheet. This will then help it keep its table structure. You can also read from the Excel file. --Is this something that may be viable to you?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the Xml serializers don't handle multiple objects in a single file. Fortunately, the Binary serializers do - see [this article](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/07/serializing-lots-of-different-objects.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some test code I wrote with LINQPad to use `BinaryFormatter` for multiple `DataSet`s:

```
var fsw = new FileStream(@"D:\testdataset.ser", FileMode.Create);
var b = new BinaryFormatter();
b.Serialize(fsw,ds);
b.Serialize(fsw,ds2);
fsw.Close();

var fsr = new FileStream(@"D:\testdataset.ser", FileMode.Open);
var rds = (DataSet)b.Deserialize(fsr);
var rds2 = (DataSet)b.Deserialize(fsr);
fsr.Close();
```

Comment: ⚠ Warning: Binary serialization can be dangerous. For more information, see [BinaryFormatter security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing. Applications should stop using BinaryFormatter as soon as possible, even if they believe the data they're processing to be trustworthy. BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I appreciate the security issues inherent in `BinaryFormatter` from the article, but most of their scenarios strain credibility which unfortunately somewhat lessens the believability of the article.

Answer (score 1):

The DataSet class has a [Merge method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.merge?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataSet_Merge_System_Data_DataSet_).  It's intent is for dataset objects where the schemas are similar/related and will combine them together.  There are [many parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/merging-dataset-contents) that can control how you want this merge to work.

**Example of Merge**

```
dataset1.Merge(dataset2,true); //true will preserve changes in dataset1 if dataset2 has matching/related data that is different
```

[A more complete example](https://www.itprotoday.com/web-development/merge-disparate-source-data).

We don't have a whole lot to go off of but based on your question it feels like Merge doesn't seem to fit your need exactly (hence my question in the comments) plus the lack of understanding why the need for one xml file and/or how the original datasets are being generated (from two external xml files outside your control for example or....).

**Idea 2**

If both datasets represent something entirely different, add to one of the datasets the tables in the other and then save.  When you read it back, you would then reverse the process to split the tables into the second dataset.

**Example of Adding Tables**

```
dataset1.Tables.Add(dataset2.Tables["tablename"]);
```

Getting back to two datasets after reading xml with Tables option would look something like:

```
foreach(DataTable table in dataset1)
{
  if(table.TableName == "TableForDataset2")
  {
   dataset2.Tables.Add(table);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save both DataSets in the same FileStream.
Then when you want to load, just load the file into an XDocument and load each dataset separately.

Here's a minimal example; clean and easy to test:

```
string fileName = "c:\\temp\\ds.txt";
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ds1 = new DataSet1();
    ds1.DataTable1.Rows.Add(1, "One");
    var ds2 = new DataSet2();
    ds2.DataTable2.Rows.Add(11, "Eleven");
    using(var fs= new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        ds1.WriteXml(fs);
        ds2.WriteXml(fs);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
}

private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xml = "<Root>" + File.ReadAllText(fileName) + "</Root>";
    var ds1 = new DataSet1();
    var ds1Xml = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Elements().ToList()[0].ToString();
    using (var r= new StringReader(ds1Xml))
    {
        ds1.ReadXml(r);
    }

    var ds2 = new DataSet2();
    var ds2Xml = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Elements().ToList()[1].ToString();
    using (var r = new StringReader(ds2Xml))
    {
        ds2.ReadXml(r);
    }
}
```